# how to solve this omsagent zombies

Tags: linux, azure, zombie-process

In my azure machine, when i SSH to it, it says +100 zombie processes.

I did

`$ ps aux | awk '$2 == 1813  { print $0 }'`

result:

> omsagent  1813  0.0  0.4 341672  8260 ?        Sl   Feb03   0:26
>   /opt/omi/bin/omiagent 10 14 --destdir / --providerdir /opt/omi/lib
>   --idletimeout 90 --loglevel WARNING

What can this be, and what is this process, what is causing this.

using this, `$  ps axo stat,ppid,pid,comm | grep -w defunct`

```
     1813   398 python <defunct>
Z     1813   400 python <defunct>
Z     1813   751 python <defunct>
Z     1813   753 python <defunct>
Z     1813  1111 python <defunct>
Z     1813  1113 python <defunct>
Z     1813  1495 python <defunct>
Z     1813  1497 python <defunct>
Z     1813  1943 python <defunct>
Z     1813  1945 python <defunct>
Z     1813  2289 python <defunct>
Z     1813  2291 python <defunct>
Z     1813  2509 python <defunct>
Z     1813  2511 python <defunct>
Z     1813  2637 python <defunct>
Z     1813  2639 python <defunct>
Z     1813  2914 python <defunct>
Z     1813  2916 python <defunct>
Z     1813  2984 python <defunct>
Z     1813  2986 python <defunct>
Z     1813  3298 python <defunct>
Z     1813  3300 python <defunct>
Z     1813  3334 python <defunct>
Z     1813  3336 python <defunct>
Z     1813  3640 python <defunct>
Z     1813  3642 python <defunct>
Z     1813  3681 python <defunct>
Z     1813  3683 python <defunct>
Z     1813  3981 python <defunct>
Z     1813  3983 python <defunct>
Z     1813  4060 python <defunct>
Z     1813  4062 python <defunct>
Z     1813  4409 python <defunct>
Z     1813  4411 python <defunct>
Z     1813  4458 python <defunct>
Z     1813  4461 python <defunct>
Z     1813  4759 python <defunct>
Z     1813  4761 python <defunct>
Z     1813  4932 python <defunct>
Z     1813  4934 python <defunct>
Z     1813  5108 python <defunct>
Z     1813  5110 python <defunct>
Z     1813  5349 python <defunct>
Z     1813  5351 python <defunct>
Z     1813  5502 python <defunct>
Z     1813  5505 python <defunct>
Z     1813  5734 python <defunct>
Z     1813  5736 python <defunct>
Z     1813  5849 python <defunct>
Z     1813  5851 python <defunct>
Z     1813  6150 python <defunct>
Z     1813  6152 python <defunct>
Z     1813  6231 python <defunct>
Z     1813  6233 python <defunct>
Z     1813  6573 python <defunct>
Z     1813  6575 python <defunct>
Z     1813  6577 python <defunct>
Z     1813  6579 python <defunct>
Z     1813  6922 python <defunct>
Z     1813  6924 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7093 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7095 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7269 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7271 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7438 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7440 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7620 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7622 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7821 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7823 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7967 python <defunct>
Z     1813  7969 python <defunct>
Z     1813  8242 python <defunct>
Z     1813  8244 python <defunct>
Z     1813  8347 python <defunct>
Z     1813  8349 python <defunct>
Z     1813  8592 python <defunct>
Z     1813  8594 python <defunct>
Z     1813  8694 python <defunct>
Z     1813  8697 python <defunct>
Z     1813  8937 python <defunct>
Z     1813  8939 python <defunct>
Z     1813  9044 python <defunct>
Z     1813  9046 python <defunct>
Z     1813  9285 python <defunct>
Z     1813  9287 python <defunct>
Z     1813  9390 python <defunct>
Z     1813  9392 python <defunct>
Z     1813  9630 python <defunct>
Z     1813  9632 python <defunct>
Z     1813  9739 python <defunct>
Z     1813  9741 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10085 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10087 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10110 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10112 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10462 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10464 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10466 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10468 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10811 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10813 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10816 python <defunct>
Z     1813 10818 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11157 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11159 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11162 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11164 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11506 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11508 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11512 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11514 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11860 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11862 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11869 python <defunct>
Z     1813 11871 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12225 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12227 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12241 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12243 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12585 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12587 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12609 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12611 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12938 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12940 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12957 python <defunct>
Z     1813 12959 python <defunct>
Z     1813 13284 python <defunct>
Z     1813 13286 python <defunct>
Z     1813 13306 python <defunct>
Z     1813 13308 python <defunct>
Z     1813 13638 python <defunct>
Z     1813 13640 python <defunct>
Z     1813 13696 python <defunct>
Z     1813 13698 python <defunct>
Z     1813 13983 python <defunct>
Z     1813 13985 python <defunct>
Z     1813 14042 python <defunct>
Z     1813 14044 python <defunct>
Z     1813 14363 python <defunct>
Z     1813 14365 python <defunct>
Z     1813 14391 python <defunct>
Z     1813 14393 python <defunct>
Z     1813 14713 python <defunct>
Z     1813 14715 python <defunct>
Z     1813 14952 python <defunct>
Z     1813 14954 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15072 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15074 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15299 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15301 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15420 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15422 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15645 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15647 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15767 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15769 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15991 python <defunct>
Z     1813 15993 python <defunct>
Z     1813 16121 python <defunct>
Z     1813 16123 python <defunct>
Z     1813 16340 python <defunct>
Z     1813 16342 python <defunct>
Z     1813 16506 python <defunct>
Z     1813 16508 python <defunct>
Z     1813 16686 python <defunct>
Z     1813 16688 python <defunct>
Z     1813 16853 python <defunct>
Z     1813 16855 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17066 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17068 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17199 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17201 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17412 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17415 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17546 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17552 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17762 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17764 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17900 python <defunct>
Z     1813 17902 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18109 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18111 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18246 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18248 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18456 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18459 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18626 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18628 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18803 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18805 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18974 python <defunct>
Z     1813 18976 python <defunct>
Z     1813 19187 python <defunct>
Z     1813 19189 python <defunct>
Z     1813 19327 python <defunct>
Z     1813 19329 python <defunct>
Z     1813 19534 python <defunct>
Z     1813 19536 python <defunct>
Z     1813 19673 python <defunct>
Z     1813 19675 python <defunct>
Z     1813 19881 python <defunct>
Z     1813 19883 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20020 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20022 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20231 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20234 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20535 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20537 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20578 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20580 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20917 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20919 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20926 python <defunct>
Z     1813 20928 python <defunct>
Z     1813 21262 python <defunct>
Z     1813 21264 python <defunct>
Z     1813 21305 python <defunct>
Z     1813 21307 python <defunct>
Z     1813 21612 python <defunct>
Z     1813 21616 python <defunct>
Z     1813 21652 python <defunct>
Z     1813 21654 python <defunct>
Z     1813 21960 python <defunct>
Z     1813 21962 python <defunct>
Z     1813 22002 python <defunct>
Z     1813 22004 python <defunct>
Z     1813 22311 python <defunct>
Z     1813 22313 python <defunct>
Z     1813 22350 python <defunct>
Z     1813 22352 python <defunct>
Z     1813 22656 python <defunct>
Z     1813 22658 python <defunct>
Z     1813 22698 python <defunct>
Z     1813 22700 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23036 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23039 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23046 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23048 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23382 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23384 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23428 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23430 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23737 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23740 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23774 python <defunct>
Z     1813 23776 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24086 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24088 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24122 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24124 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24433 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24435 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24471 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24473 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24782 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24784 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24818 python <defunct>
Z     1813 24820 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25162 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25164 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25167 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25170 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25513 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25516 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25544 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25546 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25864 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25866 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25891 python <defunct>
Z     1813 25893 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26211 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26213 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26240 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26242 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26558 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26560 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26588 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26590 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26904 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26906 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26934 python <defunct>
Z     1813 26936 python <defunct>
Z     1813 27278 python <defunct>
Z     1813 27280 python <defunct>
Z     1813 27284 python <defunct>
Z     1813 27287 python <defunct>
Z     1813 27637 python <defunct>
Z     1813 27639 python <defunct>
Z     1813 27662 python <defunct>
Z     1813 27664 python <defunct>
Z     1813 27988 python <defunct>
Z     1813 27991 python <defunct>
Z     1813 28008 python <defunct>
Z     1813 28010 python <defunct>
Z     1813 28336 python <defunct>
Z     1813 28338 python <defunct>
Z     1813 28354 python <defunct>
Z     1813 28356 python <defunct>
Z     1813 28682 python <defunct>
Z     1813 28685 python <defunct>
Z     1813 28699 python <defunct>
Z     1813 28703 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29027 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29029 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29047 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29049 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29391 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29393 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29407 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29411 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29759 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29765 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29776 python <defunct>
Z     1813 29778 python <defunct>
Z     1813 30110 python <defunct>
Z     1813 30112 python <defunct>
Z     1813 30460 python <defunct>
Z     1813 30462 python <defunct>
Z     1813 30808 python <defunct>
Z     1813 30811 python <defunct>
Z     1813 31157 python <defunct>
Z     1813 31159 python <defunct>
Z     1813 31549 python <defunct>
Z     1813 31551 python <defunct>
Z     1813 31895 python <defunct>
Z     1813 31897 python <defunct>
Z     1813 32245 python <defunct>
Z     1813 32247 python <defunct>
Z     1813 32629 python <defunct>
Z     1813 32631 python <defunct>
Z     1813 32976 python <defunct>
Z     1813 32978 python <defunct>
Z     1813 33322 python <defunct>
Z     1813 33324 python <defunct>
Z     1813 33700 python <defunct>
Z     1813 33702 python <defunct>
Z     1813 34041 python <defunct>
Z     1813 34043 python <defunct>
Z     1813 34387 python <defunct>
Z     1813 34389 python <defunct>
Z     1813 34729 python <defunct>
Z     1813 34731 python <defunct>
Z     1813 35074 python <defunct>
Z     1813 35076 python <defunct>
Z     1813 35417 python <defunct>
Z     1813 35419 python <defunct>
Z     1813 35800 python <defunct>
Z     1813 35802 python <defunct>
Z     1813 36143 python <defunct>
Z     1813 36145 python <defunct>
Z     1813 36492 python <defunct>
Z     1813 36494 python <defunct>
Z     1813 36836 python <defunct>
Z     1813 36838 python <defunct>
Z     1813 37185 python <defunct>
Z     1813 37187 python <defunct>
Z     1813 37530 python <defunct>
Z     1813 37532 python <defunct>
Z     1813 37909 python <defunct>
Z     1813 37911 python <defunct>
Z     1813 38253 python <defunct>
Z     1813 38255 python <defunct>
Z     1813 38600 python <defunct>
Z     1813 38603 python <defunct>
Z     1813 38944 python <defunct>
Z     1813 38946 python <defunct>
Z     1813 39289 python <defunct>
Z     1813 39291 python <defunct>
Z     1813 39632 python <defunct>
Z     1813 39634 python <defunct>
Z     1813 40010 python <defunct>
Z     1813 40012 python <defunct>
Z     1813 40354 python <defunct>
Z     1813 40356 python <defunct>
Z     1813 40706 python <defunct>
Z     1813 40708 python <defunct>
Z     1813 41049 python <defunct>
Z     1813 41051 python <defunct>
Z     1813 41392 python <defunct>
Z     1813 41396 python <defunct>
Z     1813 41737 python <defunct>
Z     1813 41739 python <defunct>
Z     1813 42115 python <defunct>
Z     1813 42117 python <defunct>
Z     1813 42458 python <defunct>
Z     1813 42460 python <defunct>
Z     1813 42803 python <defunct>
Z     1813 42805 python <defunct>
Z     1813 43150 python <defunct>
Z     1813 43152 python <defunct>
Z     1813 43495 python <defunct>
Z     1813 43497 python <defunct>
Z     1813 43838 python <defunct>
Z     1813 43840 python <defunct>
Z     1813 44221 python <defunct>
Z     1813 44223 python <defunct>
Z     1813 44567 python <defunct>
Z     1813 44569 python <defunct>
Z     1813 44914 python <defunct>
Z     1813 44916 python <defunct>
Z     1813 45260 python <defunct>
Z     1813 45262 python <defunct>
Z     1813 45604 python <defunct>
Z     1813 45606 python <defunct>
Z     1813 45947 python <defunct>
Z     1813 45949 python <defunct>
Z     1813 46327 python <defunct>
Z     1813 46329 python <defunct>
Z     1813 46678 python <defunct>
Z     1813 46680 python <defunct>
Z     1813 47025 python <defunct>
Z     1813 47027 python <defunct>
Z     1813 47368 python <defunct>
Z     1813 47372 python <defunct>
Z     1813 47715 python <defunct>
Z     1813 47717 python <defunct>
Z     1813 48058 python <defunct>
Z     1813 48060 python <defunct>
Z     1813 48437 python <defunct>
Z     1813 48439 python <defunct>
Z     1813 48788 python <defunct>
Z     1813 48790 python <defunct>
Z     1813 49134 python <defunct>
Z     1813 49136 python <defunct>
Z     1813 49477 python <defunct>
Z     1813 49479 python <defunct>
Z     1813 49825 python <defunct>
Z     1813 49827 python <defunct>
Z     1813 50167 python <defunct>
Z     1813 50169 python <defunct>
Z     1813 50548 python <defunct>
Z     1813 50550 python <defunct>
Z     1813 50892 python <defunct>
Z     1813 50894 python <defunct>
Z     1813 51238 python <defunct>
Z     1813 51240 python <defunct>
Z     1813 51581 python <defunct>
Z     1813 51583 python <defunct>
Z     1813 51928 python <defunct>
Z     1813 51930 python <defunct>
Z     1813 52271 python <defunct>
Z     1813 52273 python <defunct>
Z     1813 52650 python <defunct>
Z     1813 52653 python <defunct>
Z     1813 52997 python <defunct>
Z     1813 52999 python <defunct>
Z     1813 53342 python <defunct>
Z     1813 53344 python <defunct>
Z     1813 53685 python <defunct>
Z     1813 53687 python <defunct>
Z     1813 54030 python <defunct>
Z     1813 54032 python <defunct>
Z     1813 54376 python <defunct>
Z     1813 54379 python <defunct>
Z     1813 54756 python <defunct>
Z     1813 54759 python <defunct>
Z     1813 55100 python <defunct>
Z     1813 55102 python <defunct>
Z     1813 55446 python <defunct>
Z     1813 55448 python <defunct>
Z     1813 55793 python <defunct>
Z     1813 55795 python <defunct>
Z     1813 56137 python <defunct>
Z     1813 56139 python <defunct>
Z     1813 56480 python <defunct>
Z     1813 56483 python <defunct>
Z     1813 56860 python <defunct>
Z     1813 56865 python <defunct>
Z     1813 57209 python <defunct>
Z     1813 57211 python <defunct>
Z     1813 57555 python <defunct>
Z     1813 57557 python <defunct>
Z     1813 57898 python <defunct>
Z     1813 57900 python <defunct>
Z     1813 58243 python <defunct>
Z     1813 58245 python <defunct>
Z     1813 58586 python <defunct>
Z     1813 58588 python <defunct>
Z     1813 58968 python <defunct>
Z     1813 58970 python <defunct>
Z     1813 59313 python <defunct>
Z     1813 59315 python <defunct>
Z     1813 59658 python <defunct>
Z     1813 59660 python <defunct>
Z     1813 60001 python <defunct>
Z     1813 60003 python <defunct>
Z     1813 60348 python <defunct>
Z     1813 60351 python <defunct>
Z     1813 60693 python <defunct>
Z     1813 60695 python <defunct>
Z     1813 61073 python <defunct>
Z     1813 61075 python <defunct>
Z     1813 61421 python <defunct>
Z     1813 61423 python <defunct>
Z     1813 61767 python <defunct>
Z     1813 61769 python <defunct>
Z     1813 62111 python <defunct>
Z     1813 62113 python <defunct>
Z     1813 62456 python <defunct>
Z     1813 62458 python <defunct>
Z     1813 62837 python <defunct>
Z     1813 62839 python <defunct>
Z     1813 63184 python <defunct>
Z     1813 63186 python <defunct>
Z     1813 63529 python <defunct>
Z     1813 63531 python <defunct>
Z     1813 63874 python <defunct>
Z     1813 63876 python <defunct>
Z     1813 64218 python <defunct>
Z     1813 64220 python <defunct>
Z     1813 64562 python <defunct>
Z     1813 64564 python <defunct>
Z     1813 64938 python <defunct>
Z     1813 64940 python <defunct>
Z     1813 65285 python <defunct>
Z     1813 65287 python <defunct>
```

Answer (score 1):

Zombie process means process has already exited but process entry won't be removed from the Process table. we can't kill the Zombie process or delete the entry from the process table manually. only way is to kill the Zombie Process is to kill its parent process. if parent process was killed, then all its zombie process entries will be deleted from the process Table.

Comment: right but this does not cause any overflow of the process list, i mean, is this something to worrie about?

Comment: Yeah.. i gave info on Zombie process.. & how to handle them.. the actual problem would be in python.. somewhere lot of child process getting created & killed abruptly i guess.

Comment: Thanks.  That's an Azure service i installed, i removed it, https://github.com/Microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux/blob/master/docs/OMS-Agent-for-Linux.md#uninstalling-the-oms-agent-for-linux